Change default double-tap default orientation?
I've got some Blender (4.2.0) files that function differently. In some, if I hit G to move an object and X to lock it to the x-axis, it will use the World Orientation first and, if I tap X again, it will switch to the object's Local Orientation.
I've also got some files in which those two operations are reversed. G+X will lock first to the Local Orientation but G+X+X will lock to the World Orientation.
Is there any way to control which of these methods are used in a per-file basis? I haven't found anything relating to this issue online and I may just not be using the right terminology.

It depends on what you have set as Transform Orientation in the header menu. If it is set to Global (usually the default setting), X once will be global X, twice is local X. If it is set to Local, once is local X and twice is global X. Generally speaking: tapping X once will always be the chosen orientation in the menu, and X twice will be global. Unless the setting is Global, then once is the chosen orientation as well which is global in this case and twice is local as mentioned at the beginning. The Transform Orientation setting is saved with the file.

Oh, and not to forget: tapping X a third time will always unlock the axis constraint and you can move freely, no matter what Transform Orientation you have set.

Ahh, thank you! I had gotten changed to Normal somehow.

Gordon was right. The Transformation Orientation field in the header controls the default orientation mode. All I had to do was change it from Normal to Global and now my scene functions as I expected.
